# post indexed array Vue.js Axiom

Tags: vue.js, axiom

I can post an array of objects in Vue, but I'm having trouble posting a simple indexed array. I'm giving streamlined code because I think the answer lies in plain sight for the experienced.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
<section v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="deleteItem(index)">delete</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="item[index]" placeholder="enter your item here">
  </div>
</section>
<div>
  <button @click.prevent="addItem">add item</button>
</div>
```

The Vue instance data object so far:

```
data () {
  return {
    items: ['']
  }
},
```

What works:

- The user can add/delete rows on the form.
- Vue DevTools shows me an indexed array with empty fields for each row.

Error messages in the JS console:
[image: Vue error messages]

I would like to see this in the post...

```
{ "items": ["item1 input value", "item2 input value"] }
```

Instead I'm only able to get this because Vue won't react to the input changes...

```
{ "items": ["", ""] }
```

For comparison, posting an array of objects works like this:

```
<section v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="deleteItem(index)">delete</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="item.color" placeholder="enter color here">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.price" placeholder="enter price here">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.comment" placeholder="enter comment here">
  </div>
</section>
<div>
  <button @click.prevent="addItem">add item</button>
</div>
```

The Vue instance data object:

```
data () {
  return {
    items: [{ color: '', price: '', comment: '' }]
  }
},
```

Comment: Correct v-model="item[index]" to v-model="item"

Answer (score 0):

I just received the answer in another forum. 
It was so silly... item[index] just needs to be items[index].